# How to get code to execute in order in node.js

Tags: node.js

I am trying to finish my script, but for some reason i don't know, it refuses to execute in the order i put it in.

I've tried placing a 'wait' function between the JoinRequest update function and the following code, but when run, it acts as if the function call and wait function were the other way round, countering the point of the wait().

```
const Roblox = require('noblox.js')
var fs = require('fs');

var joinRequests = []

...


function wait(ms) {
  var d = new Date();
  var d2 = null;
  do { d2 = new Date(); }
  while(d2-d < ms*1000);
};


...


function updateJReqs() {
  Roblox.getJoinRequests(4745601).then((array) => {
    var i;
    var final = [];
    for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      final.push(array[i].username);
    };
    if(final === '') {
      final = '-None';
    };
    joinRequests = final
    console.log('Updated join requests.')
  });
}

function check() {
   setTimeout(() => {
       fs.readFile('Request.txt',encoding = 'utf-8', function(err, data) {
          if (err) {
              check();
          } else {
              updateJReqs();  //for some reason this function is executed alongside the below, not before it.
              // Tried putting wait(x) in here.
              console.log('Request received: ' + data)
              var solution = joinRequests
              console.log('Fuffiling request with ' + solution)
              fufillRequest(solution)
              fs.unlink('Request.txt', function(err) {
                if(err) throw err;
              });
              check();
          }
       });
   }, 400)
}

check();
```

The script is supposed to wait until a file is created (accomplished), update the list of join requests (accomplished) and then create a new file with the list of join requests in(not accomplished).

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your code you work with async code, you need to return a promise in updateJReqs and add a condition of leaving from the function because you have an infinite recursion

```
function updateJReqs() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
  Roblox.getJoinRequests(4745601).then((array) => {
    var i;
    var final = [];
    for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      final.push(array[i].username);
    };
    if(final === '') {
      final = '-None';
    };
    joinRequests = final
    console.log('Updated join requests.')
    resolve();
  });
 }
}

async function check() {
   setTimeout(() => {
       fs.readFile('Request.txt',encoding = 'utf-8', function(err, data) {
          if (err) {
              await check();
          } else {
              await updateJReqs();
              // Tried putting wait(x) in here.
              console.log('Request received: ' + data)
              var solution = joinRequests
              console.log('Fuffiling request with ' + solution)
              fufillRequest(solution)
              fs.unlink('Request.txt', function(err) {
                if(err) throw err;
              });
              // you dont have an exit from your function check();
              return 'Success';
          }
       });
   }, 400)
}

check().then(res => console.log(res));
```